# How can i get the aggregated data from SQL Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

suppose i have a table-

```
HOUR  Value
 0   10
 1    5
 2   12
```

and i want the result as
 HOUR   --->  Sum of Value

```
0    10
1    15
2    27
```

Answer (score 3):

Core ANSI SQL answer, use a correlated sub-query to sum up values:

```
select hour, (select sum(value) from tablename t2
              where t2.hour <= t1.hour)
from tablename t1
```

Answer (score 2):

As I had misread the fact it was a running total of consecutive numbers. I've updated my answer to be an alternative to the answer @jarlh gave by using `JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT T.Hour, T.value, SUM(TT.Value) S
FROM   
TimeTable T
CROSS JOIN TimeTable TT
WHERE TT.Hour <= T.Hour
GROUP BY T.Hour, T.Value
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: your `GROUP BY` doesn't sum values of previous hours. only reason you get 15 for the first hour is because you added (1, 10) as well in your insert

Comment: @ughai you're quite right. I misunderstood the expected results. I've updated my answer to use an alternative approach.

Comment: I think the OP should include **accumulate** wording in his question.